# Compare,process and delete entry in Lists in Java

Tags: java

I have two lists with objects,where list1(names) has just `fullnames without middlenams` and one more list2(fullnames) has `fullnames with middle names`. If list1 has name like `barack obama` and list2 has name `barack hussein obama`,which is same but with middlename. Then i have to delete the entry `barack obama` in list1.

I have tried below code, But it did not delete entries in list1.

```
public class Test {

       public static void main(String args[]) {

        List<String> names = new ArrayList<>()
        names.add("shannon sperling");
        names.add("john smith");
        names.add("Mary Smith");
        names.add("kim taylor");
        names.add("Barack obama");
        List<String> fullnames = new ArrayList<>();
        fullnames.add("Mary Elizabeth Smith");
        fullnames.add("Lou Henry Hoover");
        fullnames.add("Barack hussein obama");
        for(Object process :names)
        {
            if(fullnames.contains(process))
            {
               names.remove(process);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(names);

       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`List.contains()` checks for same objects. `"Barack obama"` and `"Barack hussein obama"` are obviously not the same. you need to override `contains()` or implement an own Class implementing `List` and add an additional function to compare your content in the way you like. Otherwise your code-block looks good.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for(Object process :names)
        {
            for(Object process1 :fullnames)
            {
            if(process1.contains(process))
            {
               System.out.println("match found");
            }
            }
        }
```

Comment: But the Object does not have contains method, eclipse suggests to cast process1.

Comment: this will not work, because Object process has no method `.contains()` and `String.contains()` will return `false` if the String is seperated by the middle name example.

Comment: totally agreed , was about to edit , before you guys burst out ,

Answer (score 0):

This is not really achievable using `String.contains(characterSequence)` method because the character sequence must be continuous. However, the following working code should solve your problem.

```
for(String fName: fullnames)
        {
            int i;
            for(i =0 ; i< names.size() ;i++)
            {
                String mName = names.get(i);
                String namePart[] = mName.split("\\s+");
                if(namePart.length > 1)
                {
                    int j = fName.indexOf(namePart[0]);
                    if( j > -1 && fName.indexOf(namePart[1], j+namePart[0].length()) > -1)
                        break;

                }
            }

            if(i < names.size())
            {
                System.out.println("removing "+names.remove(i));;

            }
        }

        System.out.println(names);
```